# Вызов javadcript вида $(#id).val(), что он значит?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Можно ли в него передать содержимое формы с динамически генерируемым количеством пунктов (т.е. заранее известны только типы данных, а количество выбирается пользователем).

Comment: Не забудьте что это jquery, необходимо подключить api

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
...
  <select id="select" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>

...

<script>
    function my_func() {
      var value = $("#select").val() || [];
      $("p").html("Выделенные значения:" + value.join(", "));
    }

    $("#select").change(my_func);
    my_func();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

var a = $(#id).val();
Т.е. в переменной 'a' содержиться значение поля/селекта... формы с id = 'id'

Comment: each попробуйте :)

Comment: Вы написали как считать из поля. А человеку необходимо записать.